# Chrome Extension: Reload Page from Optionspage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a optionspage, where  i have textfields and a checkbutton and a save button.
If i press the button it should reload the first active window of (in my case) "omegle.com".
I found `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().window.location.reload()`, but this just reloads the background page. Please say what you need the help me.
It tried it with sending messages 
contentscript:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message) {
    switch (message.action) {
        case "reload":
            reload()
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
});
```

background.js:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: "reload"});
```

But this doesnt work :(

### Update

```
chrome.tabs.query({
            active: true,
            title: "Omegle: Talk to strangers!"
        }, function(tabs) {
            if (tabs[0]) {
                chrome.tabs.reload(tabs[0].id)
                alert("Id:", tabs.id);
            }
        });
```

this just straight up doesnt work, for whatever reason

### Update:

```
chrome.tabs.query({url: "https://www.omegle.com/"}, function(tab) {
            var code = 'window.location.reload();';
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code: code});
        });
```

Error: Unchecked runtime.lastError: Cannot access a chrome:// URL
It seems like it wants to reload the optionspage, but i defined it should reload the omegle page

### Solution:

```
chrome.tabs.query({url: "https://www.omegle.com/*"}, function(tab) {
           chrome.tabs.reload(tab[0].id)
        })
```

Comment: chrome.tabs.reload()

Comment: @wOxxOm this reloads the optionspage and not omegle. i dont want to use a popup

Comment: Find the correct tab id using chrome.tabs.query, then use chrome.tabs.reload on that id.

Comment: updated! @wOxxOm

Comment: @wOxxOm please help me

Comment: 1) `query` retrieves an array of tabs even if it finds one tab, 2) your current code only looks for the main page. Should be `chrome.tabs.query({url: "https://www.omegle.com/*"}, function([tab])` - with array destructuring now tab is the first element.

Comment: `Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`
`chrome.tabs.query({url: "https://www.omegle.com/"}, function([tab]) {
   var code = 'window.location.reload();';
   chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab[0].id, {code: code});
  });`

Comment: It means the tab wasn't found. See what my comment says about `*`.

Comment: Doesnt work :( Unfortunatly their isnt a way written of to do it from an optionspage in the chrome api docs